# @ConstructorBinding seems not to work in Spring Boot 2.5.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, configurationproperties

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.4 and am trying to initialize an immutable class from properties:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
public class Config {
    public final String foo;
    
    @ConstructorBinding
    public Config(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```yaml
test:
  foo: bar
```

Main class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired Config config;
    public Application(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args); }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        System.out.println(config.foo);
    }
}
```

I would expect this to start and print "bar". However, it fails to start with

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in Config required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.
```

When I remove the `@ConstructorBinding` and add a setter and nullary constructor, it does work.

Comment: Don't use `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Configuration` on the same class, even if it works sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `@ConstructorBinding` in class level. And remove `@Configuration` annotation. Like this,

```
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("test")
public class Config {
    public final String foo;
    
    public Config(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Removing `@Configuration` was the key. `@ConstructorBinding` can be on the constructor. Thanks!